# I have a list, that I need to print out 10 items on every new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, range

giant list That i need to print every 10 items on a new line so instead of me writing

```
for a in range(0, 9):
    print(myList[a])

for b in range(10, 19):
    print(myList[b])
```

example input:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,171,8,19,20,21,22]
for a in range(0, 9):
    print(myList[a])

for b in range(10, 19):
    print(myList[b])

for c in range(20, 29):
    print(myList[c]
```

example output:

```
>>> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
>>> 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19
>>> 20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29
```

how could I write it in one line?

Comment: @D.Vidal for a in range(0,19): why not ?

Comment: some sample outpu added

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(myList), 10):
    print(*myList[i:i+10])
```

Comment: so simple i love it!

Comment: im not sure what the * is doing there though

Comment: how would you do it if you wanted every 10th item to print?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `zip` clustering to group the elements of the iterable.  This approach lets you use this on iterables that aren't slicable, like generators.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def print_n_on_each_line(iterable, n):
    for line in zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n, fillvalue=''):
        print(*line)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
print_n_on_each_line(a, 2)
```

prints

```
1 2
3 4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your question is that you want to have 10 items per line.

```
item1, item2, item3 ... item10
item11, item12, item13 ... item20
```

If that is the case, I would probably recommend checking out the [mod operator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

```
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if i !=0 and i%10 == 0:
        print()
    print(myList[i], end=" ")
```

Answer (score -2):

I think a bit clearer than Franciscos answer:

```
for i, e in enumerate(myList):
    newline = (i+1)%10 == 0
    print(e, end='\n' if newline else '') # or ', ', or whatever else
```

Comment: IMHO @Francisco's answer is very clear and very pythonic.